# Is it possible to customise iOS 10's Control Center?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, airplay, control-center

I would like to customise the buttons on one screen. I need media, bluetooth/airplay, alarm clock, airplane mode, flaslight and calculator. That could fit neatly into one screen. Having different panels is annoying, as the Control Center was the kind of thing you could access without looking. Now I push the wrong buttons because I'm in the media panel instead of the basic controls or vice versa. Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: You'd have to downgrade back to iOS 9...

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to modify the functions in Control Center prior to iOS 11.